# what is an efficient way to get arraylist of arraylist?

Tags: java

I have this string:

```
string1="A.1,B.2,C.4"
```

I want to get the following arraylist of arraylist:

```
<<"A","1">,<"B","2">,<"c","4">>
```

is there any way other than using for loop?
suppose that arraylists are unique, so I would have

```
Set<String> set= new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(string1.split(",")));
```

now I want to split each element in the above set on ., without using for loop.

Comment: Split it on the comma, then split each of the fragments on the period. Put the two parts into an arraylist.

Comment: the second step would need a for loop , right?

Comment: Use a hash map <string,string>

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa why? What happens if there is more than one occurrence of the same key? A map is *not* a list of pairs.

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa would u please explain more?

Comment: @Alex Yes, you'd need a loop.

Comment: Hum. How is `<<A,1>,<B,2>,<c,4>>` a list of list? What is the wanted result here? `List<List<Object>>`, `List<List<String>>`? What do you really want to do here? Where is that String coming from?

Comment: You're going to loop whether *you* do it explicitly or you use some  `Stream` utility.

Comment: Do you consider running `forEach` on a stream a "using a loop"?

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking of first splitting based on `,`. Then, split each of those on `.`, put both values in a list, and then put that list in another list. Something pseudo-code-y that should work. :)

```
string1="A.1,B.2,C.4"

stringsWithDots[] = string1.split(",");

List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for(String stringWithDots: stringsWithDots) {
    finalSplit[] = stringWithDots.split(".");
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(finalSplit);
    result.add(list1);
}
```

`"A.1,B.2,C.4"` would look like `[[A,1],[B,2],[C,4]]`

**Edit**.

[[asList source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.asList%28java.lang.Object[]%29)]

[[split](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#Pattern.split%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cint%29)] which is used to split a string [*has a loop*].

ArrayList is backed by an array. The asList function simply sets a reference to that array [[source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList)].

So, that thing you say about not using a loop. Well, be it using stream or some internal function, **loops happen**; just that you might not be seeing it in the immediate code that you write.

Comment: OP wants no loops.

Comment: @robotlos Ah! Yes. I saw that. Seemed a bit odd. Cause somewhere or the other, an internal method would use a loop anyway. I made a little edit. That split OP used, things don't get magically split into an array. It uses a loop.